# SQL Report - TOP n - Duplicates Allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the ERD diagram

[image: ERD]

Question:

Provide a report displaying the 10 artists with the most sales from July 2011 through June 2012. Do not include any video tracks in the sales. Display the Artist's name and the total sales for the year. Include ties for 10th if there are any.

Expected Result:

[image: Sample Result]

Query I have written so far

```
SELECT TOP(10) A.Name AS [Artist Name],
       SUM(I.Total) AS [Total Sales]
FROM Artist AS A
JOIN Album AS AL
ON A.ArtistId = AL.ArtistId
JOIN Track AS T
ON AL.AlbumId = T.AlbumId
JOIN InvoiceLine AS IL
ON T.TrackId = IL.TrackId
JOIN Invoice AS I 
ON I.InvoiceId = IL.InvoiceId
WHERE T.MediaTypeId != 3 and I.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2012-06-30'
GROUP BY A.Name
ORDER BY SUM(I.Total) DESC;
```

Result

[image: Actual Result]

Issues:

1) As you can see Row#2 and Row# 3 are not matching with expected result. Database you can [download from here](https://ufile.io/7b2dq).

2) I am clueless how to do "Include ties for 10th if there are any.", any suggestion ? Is [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) helpful ?

Note: `T.MediaTypeId != 3` means video tracks are not included in sales.

P.S.: This is assignment, and I am not asking for solution just to get the answer. I have tried lot of different solutions to achieve the expected result, but failed. I want to know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: `Sum(I.total)` is the sum of the invoice totals.  If an invoice has many invoice lines and some of the invoice lines are for video track, the sum would be incorrect cos it included the sale amounts of the video track.  Did you try `sum(IL.unitPrice*IL.quantity)`?

Comment: Do you know how to do nested queries? I can see a solution to this problem that is based on nested queries and the UNION operator (but I don't want to just give you the answer because I appreciate that this is an assignment).

Comment: @kc2018 yes you are right. Can you let me know how can I solve 2nd point ?

Comment: Did you try `TOP (10) WITH TIES`?

Answer (score 0):

### Partial answer as no sample data included:

You can include ties using `WITH TIES`

```
select top 10 with ties
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Also, you are using `BETWEEN` with two dates, this does not work as you would expect as the upper limit to your date range will be midnight, you will lose all information for that last day.  Use this syntax instead:

```
and I.InvoiceDate >='2011-07-01' AND I.InvoiceDate <'2012-07-01'
```

Comment: Wonder why this was downvoted, seems to do the job the OP wants, and good explanation of date logic. (Unless they expect the user here to download an unknown file for a complete stranger on the internet...)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote @Larnu, it's a pity the downvoter did not leave a comment to explain why, but partial answers are totally valid on this site as they can help to get to a full and complete answer.

Comment: I tried `select top 10 with ties`, it include all 10 ties (if any). But I need to include ties only for 10th (if there are any).